# How to change AppBar height dynamically during runtime based on the AppBar content in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, autoresize, flutter-appbar

I'm trying to implement a [flutter_tagging](https://flutterawesome.com/a-textfield-flutter-package-with-tagging-functionality/) inside the `AppBar`. I managed to add the tagged `TextField` inside the `AppBar` and to resize the `AppBar` using `PreferredSize` widget using the following code:

```
return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(110),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: HexColor('171551'),
      leading: const BackButton(),
      flexibleSpace: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48.0, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: buildTaggedSearch(),
      ),
      title: Container(),
      actions: _buildActions(),
    ),
  );
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The problem I can't manage to solve is what happens when user enter too many tags and the tags go to the second line, this is what happens:

[image]

I'm still new to Flutter and maybe I missing something, but how would I solve this issue and make the `AppBar` resize based on the content of the tags. I went over most of the questions here which talk about the AppBar resize, all of them use the `PreferredSize` widget which I use here. So I wonder if there is another option?

Answer (score 8):

There is no easy way to change the `AppBar` height at run-time. Yes, you can set it to any (fixed) height with `PreferredSize`, but once it's set, you normally cannot change it.

Even if you make your own class to extend `PreferredSize`, it will end up like this:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100); // fixed custom height

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

This `preferredSize` getter needs to return a fixed size. Its parent widget (`Scaffold`) really wants to know the app bar height, so it knows where to start rendering its body.

And if you change the above "CustomAppBar" to `Stateful`, you will quickly realize the `preferredSize` you must override, is part of the Widget not the State.

And if you do some sort of hack, like using a global variable to "trick" it:

```
Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(myAppBarHeight); // global variable
```

After changing the value in `myAppBarHeight`, the app bar still remains at its old height. You must call `setState` on widget with the `Scaffold` in order to redraw the app bar, and more importantly, redraw Scaffold body at a different position.

**So really, the solution maybe is** to control app bar height at the `Scaffold` level.

Or perhaps you should look into [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html).

Or do not try to change the app bar height at run-time, for example, use a `ListView` to horizontally scroll your chips.

Or build your own widget and don't use the app bar.

Comment: myAppBarHeight not global variable on me

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this problem, I find a solution  with **NestedScrollView** and a plugin [SliverStickyHeader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header)

Here is how I did this,

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverStickyHeader(
            sticky: false,
            header: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: kToolbarHeight,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                  .primaryColor
                                  .withOpacity(0.5),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Tag $i',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 25.0 / 2,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ];
      },
      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text('$i')),
          title: Text('Appbar with dynamic height'),
        );
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

and it is fulfilling my requirement, Plugin also support fully Sliver functionality, but I use it with as header only. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem where I want to show search along with filter which is Not Scroll with body content i.e it's fixed in the top and the result is scrollable.

Instead using AppBar i done following,

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      _buildSearchHeader(),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
              _buildSearchProductResult()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Inside **_buildSearchHeader()** i declare my app bar content.

```
SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        homePageMargin, homePageMargin, homePageMargin, 0),
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Align(child: SectionTitle("Search", fontSize: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft),
        SizedBox(height: 22),
        _buildSearchBox(), // search bar
        if(showSortSection) _buildSortSection() // sort section/ or any other 
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now I am able to create dynamic appear and scroll option perfectly.

Note: This may not perfect way to do it. If any dev knows a better way let me know here.