# How do I access the MediaQuery in a PreferredSizeWidget getSize method?

Tags: flutter

I am write a PreferredSizeWidget implementation. My widget wraps a single Text widget. To properly calculate the required height I need to multiply the text size by the MediaQuery.textScaleFactor.

The only way to know the size of the widget is to have access to the parent MediaQuery. I do not have access to the build context inside the PreferredSizeWidget getSize method.

How can I get around this limitation of PreferredSizeWidget?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the textscale factor in the constructor (as mentioned by @Scorb) like this:

```
class AppHeader extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final double textScaleFactor;

  const AppHeader({
    super.key,        
    this.textScaleFactor = 1.0,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(
        80 + (textScaleFactor * 40),
      );
}
```

and use it like so:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppHeader(
    textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -2):

In short, you can't.

The `preferredSize` getter needs to return a fixed size. It cannot be some dynamic value determined at runtime because the property is part of the `widget`, not the `element`(`state`), so you won't have access to `BuildContext` in the getter.

See this answer for some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708948/1032613

If none of those workarounds suit your needs, you can consider dropping `Scaffold` altogether (if you don't really need a `Scaffold` anyway). Or, if you use other nice `Scaffold` things such as the "floating action button", you can consider dropping the `appBar` property of `Scaffold`, and design your own custom app bar as part of the `Scaffold`'s `body`, for example, use a `Column()` as its body, and put your own app bar there.

Comment: What about just passing a context as the parameter of the custom PreferredSizeWdigets constructor?

Comment: @Scorb terrible idea, read more about what a context is, and you will see why you should never pass it to a widget constructor.

Comment: Even if it is a StatelessWidget? Because I have been doing that with zero errors in the past.